# How grep and replace String in Csv file?

Tags: powershell, csv

Please, can you help me, I am a beginner in powershell and I have a csv file, I want to select the column "Script or expected file(s)":

1. delete these different characters (P or A or Xor C or L or D) at the beginning of the string ( example PWEBX-107Q-040T.BAT to get WEBX-107Q-040T.BAT) ,
2. delete the first hyphen that is in the strings of this column (for example WEBX-107Q-040T.BAT to obtain WEBX107Q-040T.BAT) if the string begins with one of these patterns 'WEBX', 'DWHS', 'COGN', 'CLOT', 'CLAI', 'BTRE', 'BISI', 'BDDO', 'ARXL', 'AGSO', 'AGPC', 'ACTO', 'FNET' ,
3. otherwise I don't delete the dash.
4. Delete the dot with the extension (for example .KSH or .BAT ) whatever the value of the column of "Script or expected file(s)
5. replace the value in the column "Jobstream" by the value of ""Script or expected file(s)" after the above modifications.

Whatever the length of the word, my goal is to remove the first dash.      this is a csv file :

```
Jobstream;JobstreamDescription; Op num; Job;Script or expected file(s); Server; user;   location;   Job Description ; FIELD10
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;02h00
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;50;PREXX0AB;PREXX-998Q-010M.BAT;PRAXCINTREXX01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+REXX-001;Arr�t Service Applicatif;02h00
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;60;PREXX0AC;PREXX-998Q-015M.BAT;PRAXCINTREXX01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+REXX-001;Arr�t Base;02h00
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;70;PREXX0AD;PREXX-998Q-020S.KSH;SELOPRSSPSRVC01; lin-sb-axausr;F+REXX-002;Sauvegarde;02h00
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;80;PREXX0AE;PREXX-998Q-025M.BAT;PRAXCINTREXX01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+REXX-001;D{marrage Base;02h00
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;90;PREXX0AF;PREXX-998Q-030M.BAT;PRAXCINTREXX01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+REXX-001;D{marrage Appli;02h00
PAXCREXX998Q;BackUp (x)AXCINTREXX01;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;02h00
PAXCSHINTRGAAA;WAIT TRGFIC-SHIN001;9;        ;\REINSURANCE_DATA\client\01-Sources\*.xlsx;;;;START;
PAXCSHINTRGAAA;WAIT TRGFIC-SHIN001;10;PSHINAAB;technical;;;;ADDJOBSTREAM;
PAXCSHINTRGAAA;WAIT TRGFIC-SHIN001;255;        ;technical;;;;END;
PAXCSHINTRGAAB;WAIT TRGFIC-SHIN003;9;        ;\prod\SHIN\data\in\PSHIN004\*.zip;;;;START;
PAXCSHINTRGAAB;WAIT TRGFIC-SHIN003;10;PSHINAAD;technical;;;;ADDJOBSTREAM;
PAXCSHINTRGAAB;WAIT TRGFIC-SHIN003;255;        ;technical;;;;END;
PAXCSHIN100Q;Trsfrt SusiClaims  Shine;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;00h30
PAXCSHIN100Q;Trsfrt SusiClaims  Shine;40;PSHIN0AE;PSHIN-100Q-040D.BAT;PRAXCCLAIMAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-004;Extract du fichier SUSI;00h30
PAXCSHIN100Q;Trsfrt SusiClaims  Shine;50;PSHIN0AF;PSHIN-100Q-050T.BAT;PRAXCCLAIMAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-004;Arch  prepa pour UDM;00h30
PAXCSHIN100Q;Trsfrt SusiClaims  Shine;55;PSHIN0AG;PSHIN-100Q-055T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-002;Compression du fichier;00h30
PAXCSHIN100Q;Trsfrt SusiClaims  Shine;60;PSHIN0AH;PSHIN-100Q-060T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+SHIN-003;Trsft UDM shine;00h30
PAXCSHIN100Q;Trsfrt SusiClaims  Shine;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;00h30
PAXCSHIN200Q;Extrat webxl + trsf SHIN;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;00h30
PAXCSHIN200Q;Extrat webxl + trsf SHIN;40;PSHIN0AI;PSHIN-200Q-040D.KSH;PRAXCWBXLBDD01; svc_bddo_user;F+SHIN-005;export des tables en csv;00h30
PAXCSHIN200Q;Extrat webxl + trsf SHIN;45;PSHIN0AJ;PSHIN-200Q-045T.KSH;PRAXCWBXLBDD01; svc_bddo_user;F+SHIN-005;Zip et mise a dispo UDM;00h30
PAXCSHIN200Q;Extrat webxl + trsf SHIN;50;PSHIN0AK;PSHIN-200Q-050T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+SHIN-003;Udm tsfert to PRAXCAPP02;00h30
PAXCSHIN200Q;Extrat webxl + trsf SHIN;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;00h30
PAXCSHIN210D;Transfert UDM shine;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCSHIN210D;Transfert UDM shine;40;PSHIN0AL;PSHIN-210D-040T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+SHIN-003;UDM PRAXCAPP02 => SHINE;
PAXCSHIN210D;Transfert UDM shine;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCSHIN400D;check  udm transfert;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCSHIN400D;check  udm transfert;40;PSHIN0AA;PSHIN-400D-040T.BAT;PRAXSQL01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-001;Check file name  move;
PAXCSHIN400D;check  udm transfert;45;PSHIN0AB;PSHIN-400D-045T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-002;prepartion pour envoiUDM;
PAXCSHIN400D;check  udm transfert;50;PSHIN0AC;PSHIN-400D-050T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+SHIN-003;Udm transfert to shine;
PAXCSHIN400D;check  udm transfert;55;PSHIN0AD;PSHIN-400D-055T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-002;Envoi de mail fin trnsfr;
PAXCSHIN400D;check  udm transfert;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;60;PSHIN0AP;PSHIN-500Q-060T.KSH;CARAA009; SVC_SE_PROD_SHIN02;F+SHIN-006;wkf w_REF_EXTRACT;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;70;PSHIN0AQ;PSHIN-500Q-070T.KSH;CARAA009; SVC_SE_PROD_SHIN02;F+SHIN-006;zip w_REF_EXTRACT;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;80;PSHIN0AR;PSHIN-500Q-080T.KSH;CARAA009; SVC_SE_PROD_SHIN02;F+SHIN-006;UDM SHIN123 REF_EXTRACT;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;90;PSHIN0AS;PSHIN-500Q-090T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+SHIN-003;Transfrt udm praxcapp02;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;100;PSHIN0AT;PSHIN-500Q-100T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+SHIN-002;UDM SHIN124 REF_EXTRACT;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;110;PSHIN0AU;PSHIN-500Q-110T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+SHIN-003;Tsfert UDM SHIN124;00h30
PAXCSHIN500Q;Trsfrt Ref files;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;00h30
PAXCTSAD007Q;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;9;        ;technical;;;;TSAD-007Q START;21h40
PAXCTSAD007Q;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;40;PTSAD0QD;PTSAD-007Q-005S.KSH;SECLPRSSPSRVC02; lin-sb-axausr;F+TSAD-075;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;21h40
PAXCTSAD007Q;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;255;        ;technical;;;;TSAD-007Q FINISH;21h40
PAXCTSWA007Q;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;9;        ;technical;;;;TSWA-007Q START;21h40
PAXCTSWA007Q;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;40;PTSWA0RJ;PTSWA-007Q-005S.KSH;PRATSTSMMID01; SVC_SCHEDULING@alise.intraxa;F+TSWA-203;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;21h40
PAXCTSWA007Q;Bck PRGIEAXCDC02;255;        ;technical;;;;TSWA-007Q FINISH;21h40
PAXCWEBXTRGAAA;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBX001;9;        ;\prod\AGPC\WEBX.001\flg\trt.go;;;;START;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAA;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBX001;10;PWEBXAAC;technical;;;;ADDJOBSTREAM;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAA;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBX001;255;        ;technical;;;;END;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAB;Run Participations ACTOR;9;        ;\prod\AGPC\WEBX.002\in\PRTCP.csv;;;;START;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAB;Run Participations ACTOR;10;PWEBXAAD;technical;;;;ADDJOBSTREAM;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAB;Run Participations ACTOR;255;        ;technical;;;;END;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAC;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBXWX2;9;        ;\prod\AGPC\COPERNIC_LIL\WEBXL_COP\in\EC_AXACES.csv;;;;START;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAC;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBXWX2;10;PWEBXAAE;technical;;;;ADDJOBSTREAM;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAC;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBXWX2;255;        ;technical;;;;END;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAE;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBX224;9;        ;\prod\WEBX\data\in\PWEBXWX1\LIL_AH_I100_WX101_00*;;;;START;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAE;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBX224;10;PWEBXAAH;technical;;;;ADDJOBSTREAM;
PAXCWEBXTRGAAE;WAIT TRGFIC-WEBX224;255;        ;technical;;;;END;
PAXCWEBX010Q;Chek session bloquante;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX010Q;Chek session bloquante;40;PWEBX0KN;PWEBX-010Q-000T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Run script SQL;
PAXCWEBX010Q;Chek session bloquante;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;40;PWEBX0AU;PWEBX-100Q-000T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Arr�t Application;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;42;PWEBX0DX;PWEBX-100Q-002T.KSH;PRAXCWBXLBDD01; svc_bddo_user@axa-cessions.intraxa;F+WEBX-027;Arret base Oracle Webxl;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;44;PWEBX0DY;PWEBX-100Q-004T.KSH;PRAXCWBXLBDD01; svc_bddo_user@axa-cessions.intraxa;F+WEBX-027;D{marrage Base Webxl;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;50;PWEBX0AW;PWEBX-100Q-010T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;R{cup. date comptable;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;55;PWEBX0AX;PWEBX-100Q-015T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;PMD - Module 1;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;60;PWEBX0AY;PWEBX-100Q-020T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;PMD - Module 2;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;65;PWEBX0AZ;PWEBX-100Q-025T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;PMD - Module 3;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;67;PWEBX0DQ;PWEBX-100Q-027T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Script SQL Maj EXTERNA..;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;70;PWEBX0A0;PWEBX-100Q-030T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Mis en histo fic DCPT;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;75;PWEBX0BC;PWEBX-100Q-035T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;D{marrage Application;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;80;PWEBX0BU;PWEBX-100Q-040T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Export (DataPump) AGPC;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;85;PWEBX0BV;PWEBX-100Q-045T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Export (DataPump) SGR;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;90;PWEBX0B3;PWEBX-100Q-050T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+WEBX-021;Transfert Fichiers DUMP;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;100;PWEBX0D4;PWEBX-100Q-060M.KSH;PRAXCBDD; bddouser;F+WEBX-022;Arret base ReportXL;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;105;PWEBX0D5;PWEBX-100Q-065M.KSH;PRAXCBDD; bddouser;F+WEBX-022;D{marrage base Reportxl;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;110;PWEBX0B8;PWEBX-100Q-070T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Import (DataPump) WEBXL;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;115;PWEBX0B9;PWEBX-100Q-075T.KSH;PRAXCBDD; bddouser;F+WEBX-022;Rename Fichier DUMP AGPC;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;120;PWEBX0DN;PWEBX-100Q-080T.KSH;PRAXCBDD; bddouser;F+WEBX-022;Purge Fichier DUMP AGPC;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;125;PWEBX0DP;PWEBX-100Q-085T.BAT;PRAXCINFTCA01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-015;wf_ACORD;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;130;PWEBX0CC;PWEBX-100Q-090T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Import (DataPump) SGR;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;135;PWEBX0DM;PWEBX-100Q-095T.KSH;PRAXCBDD; bddouser;F+WEBX-022;Rename Fichier DUMP SGR;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;140;PWEBX0DO;PWEBX-100Q-100T.KSH;PRAXCBDD; bddouser;F+WEBX-022;Purge Fichier DUMP SGR;21h00
PAXCWEBX100Q;WEBXL / ACORD / REPORTXL;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;21h00
PAXCWEBX103H;exe requetess controle;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;08h15
PAXCWEBX103H;exe requetess controle;40;PWEBX0JR;PWEBX-103H-040M.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;lancement requetes;08h15
PAXCWEBX103H;exe requetess controle;50;PWEBX0JS;PWEBX-103H-050M.BAT;PRAXCAPP02-GIE; AXA-GIE\axc-reporting;F+WEBX-019;transfert des csv;08h15
PAXCWEBX103H;exe requetess controle;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;08h15
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;40;PWEBX0FD;PWEBX-107Q-040T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Generate Flux ACORD;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;45;PWEBX0FE;PWEBX-107Q-045T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Arch File Lst Flux;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;50;PWEBX0KZ;PWEBX-107Q-050T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Move file Lst Flux;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;55;PWEBX0K0;PWEBX-107Q-055T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Flag Flux ACORD en cours;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;60;PWEBX0K1;PWEBX-107Q-060T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Arch file lst flux 2312;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;65;PWEBX0K2;PWEBX-107Q-065T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Move files to folder UDM;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;70;PWEBX0K4;PWEBX-107Q-070T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+WEBX-021;UDM xWEBX107;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;75;PWEBX0K3;PWEBX-107Q-075T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;Move file UDM to INFTCA;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;80;PWEBX0FF;PWEBX-107Q-080T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;run ACOR.prepare.ksh;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;85;PWEBX0FG;PWEBX-107Q-085T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;run ACOR.send.ksh;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;90;PWEBX0K5;PWEBX-107Q-090T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;Move file INFTCA to UDM;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;95;PWEBX0K6;PWEBX-107Q-095T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+WEBX-021;Transfert UDM xWEBX108;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;100;PWEBX0K7;PWEBX-107Q-100T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Move file from UDM;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;105;PWEBX0K8;PWEBX-107Q-105T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Arch file lst flux 2313;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;110;PWEBX0FH;PWEBX-107Q-110T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Maj FLux WEBXL ACORD;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;115;PWEBX0K9;PWEBX-107Q-115T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Delete file flux 2313;
PAXCWEBX107Q;FLux ACORD;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX108H;Rapport RUSCHLIKON;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;21h30
PAXCWEBX108H;Rapport RUSCHLIKON;40;PWEBX0H6;PWEBX-108H-040T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;w_PHASE3_RUSCHLIKON_LITE;21h30
PAXCWEBX108H;Rapport RUSCHLIKON;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;21h30
PAXCWEBX110H;RBT-PRACEWEBXLBDD01;9;        ;technical;;;;WEBX-110H START;
PAXCWEBX110H;RBT-PRACEWEBXLBDD01;40;PWEBX0AB;PWEBX-110H-005M.BAT;PRACEWEBXLBDD01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-002;RBT-PRACEWEBXLBDD01;
PAXCWEBX110H;RBT-PRACEWEBXLBDD01;255;        ;technical;;;;WEBX-110H FINISH;
PAXCWEBX120D;Init. decomptes attendus;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX120D;Init. decomptes attendus;40;PWEBX0C0;PWEBX-120D-000T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-024;Lancement traitement;
PAXCWEBX120D;Init. decomptes attendus;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX140Q;Dump Schema AGPC (Q);9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;20h00
PAXCWEBX140Q;Dump Schema AGPC (Q);50;PWEBX0IT;PWEBX-140Q-050D.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Export Schema AGPC;20h00
PAXCWEBX140Q;Dump Schema AGPC (Q);60;PWEBX0IU;PWEBX-140Q-060T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+WEBX-021;TRTF UDM vers PRAXCAPP02;20h00
PAXCWEBX140Q;Dump Schema AGPC (Q);70;PWEBX0IV;PWEBX-140Q-070T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Copie Dump;20h00
PAXCWEBX140Q;Dump Schema AGPC (Q);255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;20h00
PAXCWEBX150Q;Trt SQL+CSV+Mail WBX AGP;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;12h00
PAXCWEBX150Q;Trt SQL+CSV+Mail WBX AGP;50;PWEBX0IX;PWEBX-150Q-050D.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-008;Begin Of JobStream;12h00
PAXCWEBX150Q;Trt SQL+CSV+Mail WBX AGP;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;12h00
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);40;PWEBX0AT;PWEBX-200Q-040T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Export WEBXL (477);
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);45;PWEBX0L7;PWEBX-200Q-045T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Move log files;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);50;PWEBX0L8;PWEBX-200Q-050T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Copy file to UDM + Arch;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);55;PWEBX0L9;PWEBX-200Q-055T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+WEBX-021;Transfert UDM (xWEBX200);
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);60;PWEBX0MA;PWEBX-200Q-060T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;Move file to INFTCA;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);65;PWEBX0MB;PWEBX-200Q-065T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;w_AlimWebXLAMB;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);70;PWEBX0MC;PWEBX-200Q-070T.KSH;CARAA009; svc_se_prod_webx01;F+WEBX-005;Move file to UDM;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);75;PWEBX0MD;PWEBX-200Q-075T.KSH;PRATFUDMGTW01; svcudmu;F+WEBX-021;Transfert UDM (xWEBX201);
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);80;PWEBX0ME;PWEBX-200Q-080T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-016;Cp files to user + Arch;
PAXCWEBX200Q;D�caissement (EXP 477);255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX259Q;WBXL - Imp Taux Cessions;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX259Q;WBXL - Imp Taux Cessions;40;PWEBX0LA;PWEBX-259Q-040T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02-GIE; AXA-GIE\axc-reporting;F+WEBX-019;Get file from Matfic;
PAXCWEBX259Q;WBXL - Imp Taux Cessions;45;PWEBX0LB;PWEBX-259Q-045T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;WEBXL - Imp  (259);
PAXCWEBX259Q;WBXL - Imp Taux Cessions;50;PWEBX0LC;PWEBX-259Q-050T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02-GIE; AXA-GIE\axc-reporting;F+WEBX-019;Push file to Matfic;
PAXCWEBX259Q;WBXL - Imp Taux Cessions;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX300M;Reboot server Webxl;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;04h05
PAXCWEBX300M;Reboot server Webxl;50;PWEBX0A1;PWEBX-300M-010M.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Arret service TOMCAT;04h05
PAXCWEBX300M;Reboot server Webxl;80;PWEBX0A4;PWEBX-300M-020M.KSH;PRAXCWBXLBDD01; svc_bddo_user@axa-cessions.intraxa;F+WEBX-027;Arret base WEBXL;04h05
PAXCWEBX300M;Reboot server Webxl;90;PWEBX0A5;PWEBX-300M-030M.KSH;PRAXCWBXLBDD01; svc_bddo_user@axa-cessions.intraxa;F+WEBX-027;Reboot Srv WEBXL BDD;04h05
PAXCWEBX300M;Reboot server Webxl;100;PWEBX0A6;PWEBX-300M-040M.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-001;Reboot serveur Appli;04h05
PAXCWEBX300M;Reboot server Webxl;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;04h05
PAXCWEBX308M;REBOOT WEBXL V3;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX308M;REBOOT WEBXL V3;40;PWEBX0DZ;PWEBX-308M-005M.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-024;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX308M;REBOOT WEBXL V3;255;        ;technical;;;;End Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX400X;Participations ACTOR V2;9;        ;technical;;;;Begin Of JobStream;
PAXCWEBX400X;Participations ACTOR V2;40;PWEBX0CH;PWEBX-400X-000T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-016;Copy Fic. -> Webxl;
PAXCWEBX400X;Participations ACTOR V2;50;PWEBX0CL;PWEBX-400X-010T.BAT;PRAXCWBXLAPP01; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-017;Trt WEBXL (Import 213);
PAXCWEBX400X;Participations ACTOR V2;60;PWEBX0CM;PWEBX-400X-020T.BAT;PRAXCAPP02; AXA-CESSIONS\SVC_SCHEDULING;F+WEBX-016;Copy Fichiers -> User;
```

Here is the code I am trying to use :

```
function updateArchiWithImportData{
        [cmdletbinding()]
        param(
            [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
            [string[]]
            $ElementCsv,
    
            [Parameter()]
            [string[]]
            $Terms = @('WEBX', 'DWHS', 'COGN', 'CLOT', 'CLAI','BTRE','BISI','BDDO','ARXL', 'AGSO', 'AGPC','ACTO','FNET')
        )
        begin {
            # create the regex patterns from terms
            $patterns = $Terms | ForEach-Object {'(^' +  $_ + '\S+?)-' }
        }
    
        process{
                        # Import the  contents of the Extract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925-01.csv and Create ElementCsv object
$ElementCsv=Import-csv  $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\Extract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925.csv -Delimiter ';'
#Loop through all the record in the CSV file
$NewModifiedElement= ForEach($Entry in $ElementCsv){
        
        if ($Entry."Script or expected file(s)" -ilike 'technical') {
                $Entry.Jobstream=$Entry.Jobstream.trimStart('PAXCLD')
        }else {
                # Get the name of jobSet without extension .ksh ou .bat
                $Entry.Jobstream=$Entry."Script or expected file(s)"
               # Write-Host $Entry.Jobstream
               # Write-Host $Entry.Jobstream.length
                $pos_last_point = $Entry.Jobstream.LastIndexOf(".")
                #Write-Host $pos_last_point
                $Entry.Jobstream = $Entry.Jobstream.Substring(0,$pos_last_point).trimStart('P')  
                $matchObj = $Entry.Jobstream | Select-String -Pattern $patterns
                $Entry.Jobstream -replace $matchObj.Pattern, '$1'
                #$Entry.Jobstream=$Entry.Jobstream.Remove($Entry.Jobstream.IndexOf("-"),1)   
        }
        
        $Entry
}
$NewModifiedElement | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Archi\Extract_AGRe_TWS_ALL_20200925-mesurecommand.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

}
updateArchiWithImportData  # Call the function
```

Comment: Is the first line of your CSV really comma separated while the rest of the file is semicolon separated?

Comment: Sorry, those are semicolons

Comment: You say in point two that you only remove the first dash if the string starts with one of a set of strings, but after point 5 you say you want to remove the first dash no matter what. Which is it?

Comment: I remove the dash only when the string contains only the quoted patterns, in absence of patterns I keep the string as it is.

Comment: I rolled back the changes to this question because it completely changed the context and intent of the original post, which I had already answered.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above it seems that use of the `-Replace` method is simplest. I would do:

```
    }else {
           $Entry.Jobstream = $Entry.'Script or expected file(s)' -replace '^(?:P|A|X|C|L|D)?(.+?)(\.(?:BAT|KSH)|$)','$1' -replace '^(WEBX|DWHS|COGN|CLOT|CLAI|BTRE|BISI|BDDO|ARXL|AGSO|AGPC|ACTO|FNET)-','$1'
    }
```

The first `-replace` does the following:

1. `^` specifies that it is the beginning of the string
2. `(?:` starts a non-capturing group
3. `P|A|X|C|L|D)` looks for any of those characters in the group
4. `?` says that the character may, or may-not exist
5. `(.+?)` is a capture group including everything up to the next group
6. `(\.(?:BAT|KSH)|$)` specifies a group that is either a dot followed by BAT or KSH, or it is the end of the string
   It then replaces the entire thing with `$1` which is the first capturing group.

That effectively removes a leading P, A, X, C, L, or D, as well as removes .BAT and .KSH

After that the second `-replace` just looks for those strings you want to remove the dash after, and removes the dash.

Comment: Hope to see this answer accepted, unlikely tho since op hasn't accepted any answer to all questions...

Comment: Can you confirm that the recent edits by OP to the question still left it in an aswerable state? Is the information which you based your answer on still there? If not, let's undo the edit and inform OP. Otherwise your post might fall victim to a moving target effect and look either not applicable or strangely clairvoyant.

Comment: @Yunnosch No, the changes to the OP have not left it in an answerable state. They completely changed their intent, and the criteria for their original question.

Comment: Then I would second you on undoing the edit. Go ahead, just leave an explaining comment.